# How to set contraints for self sizing UITableViewCell using Auto Layout in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a self-sizing tableViewCell that presents comments.  If the current user commented I present edit and delete buttons.  My contraints work perfectly in this case.  All of my constraints are set in Interface Builder.

The challenge now is that when a comment doesn't belong to a user I set .isHidden = true for both the edit and delete buttons.  How can I adjust my constraints for this new scenario?

[image]

EDIT: The issue is when I set .isHidden to true on the buttons, I want to cell height to shrink as the button space is empty.

Comment: Are the buttons being shown or hidden based on a value? Or is it possible they will be shown, and then hidden after something else happens? That is, when you are in `cellForRowAt`, is *that* when you determine whether to show or hide the buttons?

Comment: Yes DonMag at cellForRowAt.. I check:  if comment.userID == appUserID.
if the comment belongs to the user I show the buttons else I hide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

Toggle the `.isActive` state of the constraint from the bottom of the buttons to the bottom of the cell, along with the `.isHidden` state.

To do so, add a vertical space constraint from the bottom of your `date` label to the bottom of the cell, set to `>= 4` (or however much "padding" you want when the buttons are not there).

Add an `@IBOutlet` for the spacing constraint from the bottom of the Edit button to the bottom of the cell. In your image, it shows as `bottom = Edit Button.bottom + 2`. When you ctrl+drag the constraint from IB to your source file it will generate the IBOutlet line like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var editButtonBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

You will need to edit that line, though... Constraints are deallocated when deactivated, unless you have a "strong" reference to it. So, simply remove the `weak` modifier:

```
@IBOutlet var editButtonBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Now, in `cellForRowAt`, you can do:

```
    cell.deleteButton.isHidden = !(comment.userID == appUserID)
    cell.editButton.isHidden = !(comment.userID == appUserID)
    cell.editButtonBottomConstraint.isActive = (comment.userID == appUserID)
```

Although, personally, I would make that a function inside the cell.

---

Based on your cell design, though, I'm guessing `commentsLabel` is possibly / probably a multi-line label? And you'll want the cell to expand vertically if the comment is, say, 8 lines long? If so, you still have a few constraint relationships to work out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

Instead of hiding the `buttons`, you can:

**1.** Set `UIButton` `title` to `nil`.

**2.** Take the `IBOutlet` of `UIButton` `height constraint` and set it to `0` whenever you want to hide the button.

**Example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
    if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        cell.button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
        cell.buttonHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

This will handle the constraints according to your requirement.

Comment: Quick notes... you should not implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` when using Auto-sizing cells - just set the table view's `.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `viewDidLoad`. Also, setting an actual value for `.estimatedRowHeight` can improve scrolling performance - and again, just set it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This solution could work... but it might leave too much vertical space between the "date" label and the bottom of the cell.

Comment: You need to handle that separately. Another solution could be to use removeFromSuperview with the buttons. But in that case you need more handling than this one.

Comment: There might be other ways to achieve this. I implemented using this one. Would love to know other solutions as well.